# Ошибка компиляции React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Я сделал проект react js. Когда я его запустил увидел это:
**Failed to compile**

./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css) Error: No valid exports main found for 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\book-shop\react-book\node_modules\colorette'

В проекте ничего не делал. Не понимаю, что делать

Comment: Надеюсь, поможет - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9273

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это должно помочь:

1. Обновить node.js;
2. Удалить create-react-app следующей командой: `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`;
3. Далее создать новое react-приложение, используя команду: `npx create-react-app myapp`.